# Passing data between ViewControllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass an integer value between `UIViewControllers`, new to iOS and having problems.

In the `UIViewController` where the value is being set, there are no problems. But after the value is set `NSLog` is showing that the value is null in the second `UIViewController`.

My app is going to use the horizontal slider to determine the length of time in between a `UIImage animationDuration` in a different `UIViewController`.

This method is correctly receiving the value from the horizontal slider. I initialized an instance of the "other" `UIViewController`, `imageview.somedata` belongs to the other view controller. I know the value is being passed correctly because of the `NSLogs` below.

```
- (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
imageView = [[GTImageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GTImageView" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"text value = %@", myTextField);
NSString *textValue = [myTextField text];
int value = [textValue floatValue];
if (value < 0) value = 0;
if (value > 100) value = 100;
mySlider.value = value;
sliderValue = &value;
NSLog(@"sliderValue = %d", *(sliderValue));
myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1d", value];
if ([myTextField canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
imageView.someData = *(sliderValue);
NSLog(@"imageView.someData = %d", imageView.someData);
}
```

This is the top of that implementation file

```
    #import "GTSettingsVC.h"
    #import "GTImageView.h"
    #import "GTImageView.m"
    @interface GTSettingsVC ()
    @end

    @implementation GTSettingsVC
    @synthesize mySlider, myTextField;
    @synthesize sliderValue;
```

That header file

```
    #import "GTImageView.h"
    @interface GTSettingsVC : UIViewController
    {
    IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
    GTImageView *imageView;
    int *sliderValue;
    }

    @property (nonatomic) int *sliderValue;
```

The header file of the view controller I am trying to send the data to

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface GTImageView : UIViewController
    {
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
     UIPageControl* pageControl;
     int *someData;
     }
     @property (nonatomic) int *someData;
```

The implementation file where I want the variable someData to have the value I gave it in the first controller. NSLog is returning null in this implementation.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.



      UIImageView *animatedImageView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc] i nitWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,      55, 400, 550)];
      [self.view addSubview:animatedImageView];

       animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0052.JPG"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0054.JPG"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0081.JPG"],
                                     nil];
      NSLog(@"some data = %@", someData);
   //   NSLog is returning null
      int x = someData;
      animatedImageView.animationDuration = 
      x * [animatedImageView.animationImages count];
      [animatedImageView startAnimating];
      [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];

      }
```

Comment: There are many different ways to pass data between viewcontrollers. I want to know the flow structure of your viewcontroller. Do you use UINavigation? Do you use Segue?

Comment: I am using UINavigation Controller in my App Delegate

Comment: I have added an answer below. If my answer is good enough, please upvote and mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have yet to grasp the concept/idea for **View Controller Life Cycle** and also **Model View Controller (MVC)**.

The **GTImageView** that you defined and initiated in **changeButtonPressed** for your First View Controller (**GTSettingsVC**) is a local object/instance for **GTSettingsVC**. If your view controller transition from **GTSettingsVC** to **GTImageView**, the data will not pass to  there.

Since you are using `UINavigationController`, I believe you have `Segue`. The easiest way to pass data for `UINavigationController` is using `prepareForSegue`. You will have to prepare the data that you want to pass to the second view controller in this method before the transition to it.

You also make some mistake in **GTImageView**. **someData** is not an object, it should not have *****. And also try **not to use variable**, use just the **property** in stead. It should be:-

```
 @property (nonatomic) int someData;
```

In **GTSettingsVC.M**, add the following function:-

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  GTImageView * viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
  viewController.someData = 99;
}
```

In **GTImageView.H**

```
@interface GTImageView : UIViewController
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
    UIPageControl* pageControl;
}
@property (nonatomic) int someData;
@end
```

In **viewDidLoad** in **GTImageView.M**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImageView *animatedImageView =
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,55, 400, 550)];
  [self.view addSubview:animatedImageView];

  animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0052.JPG"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0054.JPG"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0081.JPG"],
                                     nil];
  NSLog(@"some data = %d", self.someData);
  int x = self.someData;
  animatedImageView.animationDuration =
  x * [animatedImageView.animationImages count];
  [animatedImageView startAnimating];
  [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
}
```

I added a sample project to Github for your reference:-
https://github.com/voyage11/PassingDataTest

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to take int *. Replace it by int and assign the value directly rather than address.

Comment: What does the the pointer have to do with moving the data from controller to controller? And if it were a pointer problem, NSLog would've returned an address in memory, not a null value.