# How to display specific array based on choice from previous controller

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have two table controllers connected to each other. The first table displays the information from my nationality array [american, Asian, italian].  If a user selects the American cell, I want four items in the american item array to be displayed in the second view controller.  And vice versa with the Asian and Italian arrays and more specifically the Asian and Italian items array in the second table controller.

How would I go about displaying specific arrays/items in the second controller when the second table display is dependent upon the user choice in the first table controller?

Can reword if necessary.

Comment: How are you moving to the second view controller?  Via a segue?  Typically you would pass the value to the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Check out links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802901/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers-in-ios and http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/. Still if you are not sure let us know how are you going to the second view controller.

Comment: I would be using the prepareforsegue function, but how would I go about specifying which array to send over using if statement in the prepareforsegue function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TABLEONE:

```
class TableOne: UITableViewController {

    var countries = ["American", "Asian", "Italian"]
    var items = [["Mcdonalds", "BurgerKing", "Big Boy"], ["PFChangs", "China One Buffet"], ["Pizza House", "Pizza Hit", "Olive Garden", "Maggianos"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
        {
            //problem here with "sender"
            let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
            if let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
            {
            var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
            nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return countries.count
           }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let selected = countries[indexPath.row]
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellone") as TableOneCell
        cell.tableonecelllabel.text = selected
        return cell

    }
}
```

TABLE TWO:

```
class TableTwo: UITableViewController {

    var items: [String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let items = items
        {
            return items.count
        }
        else
        {
           return  0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let selected = items![indexPath.row]
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celltwo") as TableTwoCell
        cell.tablecelltwolabel.text = selected
        return cell

    }   
}
```

YOU SHOULD CORRECT ALSO THE TABLEVIEWCELL identifier of celltwo.

Comment: in this example, what would ".value" and "yourValvue" represent using the items mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, Im going to update it applied to your own problem

Comment: Appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: So the "cellIndexPath" simply references the country within the array but how are the american items pushed into the next display?

Comment: So i suppose, how would i go about setting up the selectedCountry property in the next view controller?  Would I have to set up a property for each countryList array?

Comment: option A) You can have all items (of all different nationalities) already in the next display, showing some of them depending which is the value of "selectedCountry".
option B) instead of having selectedCountry property in yourNextViewController, you can change it by an array property and pass directly the american items  or asian items, etc..  Choosing this option you should create an array of arrays in the previious view controller which contains all the options from yourNextViewController(position 1: all american item array,position 2: all asian items array...etc)

Comment: No, you need just an array of arrays, just one property:

var nationalityItems: String[][] = [["AsiaItem1","AsiaItem2","AsiaItem3"],["AmericanItem1","AmericanItem2","AmericanItem3"],.... ]

Comment: Alright.  I believe I understand the basics of what you're getting across, but I have to internalize them for the moment.  Hopefully, you do not mind if i post a follow-up tomorrow regarding the issue?  Regardless, thank you for your input, Javier Flores Font.

Comment: just wanted to make sure I am understanding the code.                                                                                                           var cellIndexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForCell                                      \\this refers to the specific country in the "countries array" by number           NextVC.countriesItemsArray=arrayofcountries[cellIndexpath.row]                 \\index path of the countriesitemsarray (double array) = same location of parent country in the first controller? Correct?

Comment: cellIndexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForCell   ----> exactly it refers to the country selected  , it gives you the indexPath of the cell selected.
doing countriesitemsarray [cellIndexpath.row] you get the  items of the selected country, and then you pass this items to the next view controller

Comment: Awesome, I think I understand!  I'll try it out and see how it goes, but once again,  thanks again, JFF!

Comment: No worries mate, could you vote my answer please? thanks! Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: I'm working on implementing this code and concept right now, how would I go about creating the "selectedCountry" property?

Comment: also, for the "var cellIndexPath = self.tableview.indexPathforCell(sender), I reveice an error "(UITableView, numberOfRowsinSection: Int) -> does not have a member named "indexPathforCell".  Thoughts?

Comment: btw,  indexPathforCell  exists in swift:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForCell:

Comment: You have a lot of bugs... ahaha

Comment: I am aware.  Most of them revolving around the indexpathforcell function.  Thoughts overall though?

Comment: I honestly cannot thank you enough.  I do not have a yet solid understanding of optionals, but ill be sure to look into more now that I know my code deeply revolved around them.  99.9% there, but I do have one small bug, and it's not apparent to me.  ideas? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yiqrymrrtlda1a5/AACzRtM4RLy6dT5Ksf3JRYeJa?dl=0

Comment: no worries, i hope it help :)  I recommend you to read this:  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class TableOne: UITableViewController {

var countries = ["American", "Asian", "Italian"]
var items = [["Mcdonalds", "BurgerKing", "Big Boy"], ["PFChangs", "China One Buffet"], ["Pizza House", "Pizza Hit", "Olive Garden", "Maggianos"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
    {
        //problem here with "sender"
        let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
        if let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
        {
        var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
        nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return countries.count
       }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let selected = countries[indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellone") as TableOneCell
    cell.tableonecelllabel.text = selected
    return cell

}
}

class TableTwo: UITableViewController {

var items: [String]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let items = items
    {
        return items.count
    }
    else
    {
       return  0
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let selected = items![indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celltwo") as TableTwoCell
    cell.tablecelltwolabel.text = selected
    return cell

}   
}
```

Big thanks to Javier for the code and insight!